# Excel: Create sequential value based on input from multiple drop downs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequential

I am looking for some assistance. I want to be able to generate a name from input on multiple drop down lists of a standardized naming convention and I can not determine how to complete this. As an example this is just data generated for the example. I need to have a value generated by drop down list selections where If the name already existed it would append it to add the next sequential number. Can anyone advise of where I should start with this? I have spend hours searching with no luck.

[image]

Currently I have the drop down list selections, that are then matched via INDEX and reference the corresponding code abbreviation in columns F:J, that are then displayed out using `=F5&G5&H5&I5&J5"`.

I can not determine how to add the sequence to this starting with 1, and if 1 already exists moving to 2. Example `AAAARE_BSKS1` exists but the same selections are chosen the new name for that selection would be `AAAARE_BSKS2`.

[image]

Comment: This is going to be a little complicated with a helper column, or Excel O365, and quite a bit more complicated without.

Comment: @MaxR, would you be able to point me in a direction that may provide more information? I do have Excel O365, and have no issue adding helper columns, I just can not find a method to append a sequential number to my name. My current method of thought was to add a column that added a 1 to the end of every row. Then I was trying a countif column matched cell to list duplicate. Then I could have each of the duplicates append another 1, but I have not been successful in making this work.

Comment: I was able to get it figured out. I took my generated name, I then added a new column beside it that did a =COUNTIF($J$2:$J26,J26) to find the number of time the name repeated itself prior to this cell. From there I added another column that did a =CONCATENATE(J26:K26) to add the name, with the number of occurrences after, and it worked perfectly.  Just wanted to post this in case anyone runs into the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent!  I was typing a suggestion about a helper column as you posted this!  A best practice is, if you figure it out, then you should post your own answer below with enough detail for someone else to follow, and then mark your own answer as the best answer.  That way it (a) marks the question answered so other "solvers" don't investigate it, and (b) improves the likelihood of someone having a similar challenge finds your answer.  Your COUNTIF() approach with a helper column is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it figured out. I took my generated name, I then added a new column beside it that did a =COUNTIF($J$2:$J26,J26) to find the number of time the name repeated itself prior to this cell. From there I added another column that did a =CONCATENATE(J26:K26) to add the name, with the number of occurrences after, and it worked perfectly. Just wanted to post this in case anyone runs into the same issue. Thank you.